# How do I explore the current commitment transaction for a channel?

Tags: lightning-network-daemon

I would like to see how a commitment transaction for a given payment channel looks like (without actually closing the channels and transmitting the transaction to the network :)

I assume that all of the building blocks (such as balances) are somewhere in `channel.db`. Is there a way to quickly get this information out and construct the commitment transaction out of it without much coding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer by Oliver Gugger (guggero):

> You can use the `dumpchannels` command of `chantools`:
> https://github.com/guggero/chantools#dumpchannels That will show you
> the commitment transaction inputs and outputs for both parties.
> Remember to shut down lnd first, otherwise chantools will block on
> trying to open the channel DB.